# Full screen image for Drupal site home page

Tags: drupal, background-image, fullscreen

I'm new to Drupal and I'm trying to set up the home page for a site I'm working on.  Here is an example for what I'm shooting for: https://www.missionfed.com/

I want a full screen image as the background and sections of boxes very similar to the example given.  I'm unsure of what I need to do this.  Should I be using Panels/Views?  Change the page.tpl.php file?  Or something else?

Also, I'm new to PHP so this should be a fun learning curve.  Basically, I just need to be pointed in the right direction .

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Background image to div next to body you can apply by using CSS . In your example it looks like:

```
#home #pagebg {
  background: url(/path_to_image) no-repeat center top;
  -webkit-background-size: 2560px 1440px;
  -moz-background-size: 2560px 1440px;
  background-size: 2560px 1440px;
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
}
```

And layout similar to given site indeed can be done with panels/views (and maybe context). Just choose closest layout and fill it with views and blocks.

Another way is to define manually new regions in .info file and output it in page.tpl.php. But it require more knowledges and time. So you can stick with panels.